# change my json format to format Highcharts

Tags: php, json

> code php mysql     `$ok = mysql_query("SELECT *,YEAR(NOW()) 
> AS ok ,MONTH(NOW())FROM bulan WHERE bulan<=MONTH(NOW()) ");`
>
> ```
> while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($ok)){
> ```
>
> $cek=$r1['bulan'];  $cek2=$r1['ok'];  $gab=$cek2."-".$cek; 
>   $sql="SELECT (SELECT 
>                  COUNT(p.perkara_id) 
>                   FROM
>                     perkara AS p 
>                     LEFT OUTER JOIN perkara_putusan AS putus 
>                       ON p.perkara_id = putus.perkara_id 
>                   WHERE p.alur_perkara_id 
>                     AND LEFT(p.tanggal_pendaftaran, 7) < '$gab' 
>                     AND (
>                       putus.tanggal_putusan IS NULL 
>                       OR LEFT(putus.tanggal_putusan, 7) >= '$gab') AND p.`jenis_perkara_kode`!='LL'
>
> ```
>            )AS sisa_bulan_lalu     FROM bulan WHERE bulan=$cek ";
> ```
>
> $sql2="SELECT   (  SELECT 
>                 COUNT(p.perkara_id) 
>               FROM
>                 perkara AS p 
>               WHERE p.alur_perkara_id 
>                 AND LEFT(p.tanggal_pendaftaran, 7) = '$gab' AND p.`jenis_perkara_kode`!='LL'
>
> ```
>            )AS sisa_bulan_lalu     FROM bulan WHERE bulan=$cek ";
> ```
>
> $sql3="SELECT   (  SELECT 
>                 COUNT(p.perkara_id) 
>               FROM
>                 perkara AS p 
>                 LEFT OUTER JOIN perkara_putusan AS putus 
>                   ON p.perkara_id = putus.perkara_id 
>               WHERE 
>                 LEFT(p.tanggal_pendaftaran, 7) <= '$gab'
>                 AND LEFT(putus.tanggal_minutasi, 7) = '$gab' AND p.jenis_perkara_kode!='LL'
>                  )AS sisa_bulan_lalu     FROM bulan WHERE bulan=$cek ";
>
> $hasil = mysql_query("$sql"); $hasil2 = mysql_query("$sql2"); $hasil3
>   = mysql_query("$sql3");
>
> $rows1 = array(); $rows1['name'] = 'sisa_bulan_lalu';
>   while($r=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){   $rows1['data'][] =
>   $r['sisa_bulan_lalu']; }
>
> $rows2 = array(); $rows2['name'] = 'masuk_bulan_ini';
>   while($r2=mysql_fetch_array($hasil2)){   $rows2['data'][] =
>   $r2['sisa_bulan_lalu']; }
>
> $rows3 = array(); $rows3['name'] = 'minutasi_bulan_ini';
>   while($r3=mysql_fetch_array($hasil3)){   $rows3['data'][] =
>   $r3['sisa_bulan_lalu']; }
>
> $result = array(); array_push($result,$rows1);
>   array_push($result,$rows2); array_push($result,$rows3); print
>   json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
>
> } My code that generates this json format
>
> > [{"name":"sisa_bulan_lalu","data":[67]},
> >   {"name":"masuk_bulan_ini","data":[23]},
> >   {"name":"minutasi_bulan_ini","data":[17]}]
> >
> > [{"name":"sisa_bulan_lalu","data":[66]},
> >   {"name":"masuk_bulan_ini","data":[22]},
> >   {"name":"minutasi_bulan_ini","data":[27]}]
> >
> > [{"name":"sisa_bulan_lalu","data":[53]},
> >   {"name":"masuk_bulan_ini","data":[11]},
> >   {"name":"minutasi_bulan_ini","data":[12]}]
> >
> > [{"name":"sisa_bulan_lalu","data":[33]},
> >   {"name":"masuk_bulan_ini","data":[20]},
> >   {"name":"minutasi_bulan_ini","data":[39]}]
> >
> > > **I want the data could be formatted in the following way so
> > >       that I can plug in to series option in HighCharts:**
> > >
> > > ```
> > >   [{
> > >             name: 'Sisa Bulan Lalu',
> > >             data: [67,66,53,33]
> > >         }, {
> > >             name: 'Masuk Bulan Ini',
> > >             data: [23,22,11,20]
> > >         }, {
> > >             name: 'Minutasi Bulan Ini',
> > >             data: [17,27,12,39]
> > >         }]
> > > ```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: are these keys static or changes ?

Comment: @Robert  sorry I've reposted my PHP code.

Comment: @Sajeetharan changes From My Database

Comment: did my answer work? please mark as answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry I've been here, thank you for helping me. answers of your own right. but how do I make a json as you make ?? json result I do not like the program you created (the result is above). I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @karelsrt89 no i dont get what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
var data = [{
    "name": "sisa_bulan_lalu",
    "data": [67]
}, {
    "name": "masuk_bulan_ini",
    "data": [23]
}, {
    "name": "minutasi_bulan_ini",
    "data": [17]
}, {
    "name": "sisa_bulan_lalu",
    "data": [66]
}, {
    "name": "masuk_bulan_ini",
    "data": [22]
}, {
    "name": "minutasi_bulan_ini",
    "data": [27]
}, {
    "name": "sisa_bulan_lalu",
    "data": [53]
}, {
    "name": "masuk_bulan_ini",
    "data": [11]
}, {
    "name": "minutasi_bulan_ini",
    "data": [12]
}, {
    "name": "sisa_bulan_lalu",
    "data": [33]
}, {
    "name": "masuk_bulan_ini",
    "data": [20]
}, {
    "name": "minutasi_bulan_ini",
    "data": [39]
}];
  var res = [];
  var axis = [];
  data.forEach(function(o) {
    var exists = res.find(p => p.name === o.name);    
    if (exists) {
      exists.data.push(o.data[0]);
    } else {
      axis.push(o.name);
      res.push(o);
    }
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/zgk4c8n8/)**